# What are space types, callbacks, and listeners?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to learn the Python API and I figured I'd start at the beginning with [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/info_quickstart.html). It says:

**The Blender/Python API can’t (yet)…**

- Create new space types.
- Assign custom properties to every type. *(I assume given the context, every "type" is referring to the aforementioned space types)*
- Define callbacks or listeners to be notified when data is changed.

Could someone explain what these things are, so I can better understand what I can and can't do?